# Passing Activity/Fragment as a listener parameter to VM method

Tags: android, mvvm, android-architecture-components

So I'm fairly new to MVVM. So I'm fetching my data in my VM and I'm passing in the Activity/fragment as a listener in the method call.

The reason I'm doing this is because I'm going to have a callback if there was to be an error. So I'd handle it in the activity/fragment with a dialog.

I'm not sure if I'm breaking MVVM here? If i'm making any other errors with this pattern, please let me know.

Thanks

In my view, fragment/activity

```
/*creating and using my VM inside my fragment*/
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    //Create and observe data for any changes throughout the lifecycle
    final OverviewViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(OverviewViewModel.class);

    //get info
    viewModel.getUserInfo(this);

    observeViewModel(viewModel);
}

//Listener in the activity/fragment that will handle an error in the request 
@Override
public void onTokenExpired() {

    ExpiredTokenDialogFragment dialogFragment = new ExpiredTokenDialogFragment();
    dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), EXPIRED_DIALOG);
}
```

My View model where i make request.

```
public void getUserInfo(AuthenticationListener listener){
    mUserInformationObservable = mRepository.getUserInfo(listener);
}
```

My retrofit request

```
public LiveData<UserInformation> getUserInfo(final AuthenticationListener authenticationListener){
        final MutableLiveData<UserInformation> data = new MutableLiveData<>();

        mService.fetchFollowers().enqueue(new Callback<UserInformation>() { 
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UserInformation> call, retrofit2.Response<UserInformation> response) {

            //note, the result is in data. Calling response.body.string twice results in an empty string
            if(response.body()!=null)  data.setValue(response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UserInformation> call, Throwable t) {
            if(t instanceof UnauthorizedException){
                data.setValue(null);
                mToken.setAccessToken(null);
                authenticationListener.onTokenExpired();
            }
        }
    });

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Use liveData and observe the changes in activity or fragment. You don't need listeners. Looking into https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample will definitely help

Answer (score 1):

Using a listener is not recommended. The android-architecture project uses a [SingleLiveEvent](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java) class for events like navigation or displaying a `Snackbar`. You can use the same class for showing a dialog.

In your `OverviewViewModel` you can add another field:

```
final SingleLiveEvent<Void> tokenLiveData = SingleLiveEvent<Void>();
```

in your `onFaliure` callback you can use:

```
tokenLiveData.call()
```

instead of the callback.

In your activity subscribe to `tokenLiveData` and show a dialog when it emits a value.